# Jenkins and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a linux machine with Jenkins installed on it. It executes variety of different jobs on other linux machines.

Now - I would like to connect to a Windows machine and execute a PS script. Is it possible to do that from the Linux Jenkins by installing PS plugin (note that I do not want to execute a PS script on a local linux machine but execute all that on remote hosts)? If not, what is the proper way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can run jobs on slave windows machine with Linux master.

1. Add windows machine as a new node(slave), give it a distinct label. The following link can help you in adding new slaves (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines)
2. Go to job where you want to run PS script on windows machine and check the option "Restrict where this project can be run". Enter name of your windows machine label here.

To execute all jobs on remote machines, you can give all of them a separate label and use the step 2 to only use them for your jobs.

To execute job on local host you can enter "master" in the restrict run editbox.